# Edit existing Google Maps element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For a website I'm using Google Maps to add polylines to a map to display a route. Some routes consist of multiple legs (stages) and I'm trying to add the polylines 'on request'. So only if a user chooses to show a leg, it will draw the polyline. Also the user might choose a completely different route and this new set of polylines should be drawn on the map as well.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out or find how to *select* an existing map. I start out by creating a map using the following code:

`qMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mP.target), mapOptions);`

`mP.target` contains a string with the canvas `id` and `mapOptions` is just a object with some options, nothing special.

So I do all kind of stuff with `qMap`, like adding markers, drawing polylines etc. And this shouldn't just be done at map initiation, but also when the user wants to add something. `qMap` isn't a global variable and I rather not have it being a global either.

I've tried `qMap = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mP.target))` and other similar methods. With no success. I'm hoping you can help me out finding a way to this without global variables! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could try.

1) Wrap your code in an immediately invoked function. This way any variables are contained within the function's scope and don't escape to pollute the global variable space which I guess is your main concern.

```
(function () {

  var mapGlobal = new google.maps.Map(target, options);

  function thatDoesSomething(){
    // do something with mapGlobal
  }

}());
```

2) Use a static object which might be handy for organising your code.

```
var Map = {

  map: new google.maps.Map(target, options),

  thatDoesSomething: function () {
    // do something with this.map
  }

};
```

3) Or combine them.

```
(function () {

  var Map = {

    map: new google.maps.Map(target, options),

    thatDoesSomething: function () {
      // do something with this.map
    }

  };

}());
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used option 2 and it works just the way I want it. Only thing is I've got to have a `object` for each map. Thanks!